# Firebase chat notifications via PHP to SMS + EMAIL

Tags: php, firebase, sms, firebase-realtime-database

We have firebase chat application (check any chat example or tutorial) that will have same copy as our.

We would like to sent email notification or sms message, if user hasn't seen the chat message yet.

We can connect to firebase database with php and check all the messages, if they are seen or not. but It's not really proper way of doing it.

Does anyone have idea how we can implement that, so we can track of all the messages and if they haven't seen it, then sent the email / sms notification based on user preference?

I just want to know how we can do that with firebase. if it was just php and mysql. it was really easy to do this.

Comment: have you tried REST api.

Comment: Yes, but we don't want to read all the messages to know which is new message and which is old. that would cost us lots of crobjob reading or time, if it gets huge.  need more efficient solution.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this can be done efficiently in Firebase. You will have to setup a cron job to fetch the messages which are not seen and trigger SMS/Email fallback.

I would recommend using Applozic (https://www.applozic.com) for Chat related stuff and Firebase for storing user meta data and other data.
Applozic provides a single click configuration to enable Webhook/SMS/Email fallback, along with that you will get all the whatsapp like chat features along with full UI with no need to write any additional code.